# Powershell Regex not triggering

Tags: .net, regex, powershell, powershell-2.0

I'm having a problem getting a Regex to extract a portion of a string and I can't see what I have done wrong.

The string:

```
Backup job DailyBackupToNAS completed successfully.   Destination: Network location Start time: 01/05/2013 05:00:28 End time: 01/05/2013 05:39:13 Duration: 00:38:45.5875346
```

The code:

```
$destinationregex = "Destination: (.*)Start time:"
If ($message -match $destinationregex)
{
    $destination = $matches[1]
}
```

I am trying to extract the text Network Location

Any pointers would be appreciated!

As requested a fuller scope of code
$events = get-eventlog application -source BackupAssist -newest 50

```
Foreach ($event in $events)
{
  $message = $event.message
  $destinationregex = "Destination: (.*)Start time:"
  If ($message -match $destinationregex)
  {
    $destination = $matches[1]
  }
  Else
  {
    $destination = "Unknown"
  }
  Write.Host $destination
}
```

Comment: I've tested using your example and works for me. Add what is your error...

Comment: It's not erroring but destination ends up an empty variable.

Comment: Check the content of `$message` and if is of type [string]. If you simulate using your example you'll see that regex is good, I would add just an extra space after `(.*)` to exclude it from the capture.

Comment: Variable type is fine as there is a regex underneath running on the same variable $message and that executes properly. Added the space and no difference.

Comment: Hmm however if I put the string directly in as a variable it works OK.

Comment: Maybe the underneath regex change the value of $message?

Comment: Already tried that I moved it to be the first one and didn't work. GetType suggests it is a System.String but when I write-host $message it formats it onto multiple lines, I'm not sure how it knows to do that as the message is just one line.

Comment: try with this regex: `"(?m)Destination: (.*) Start time:"`

Comment: No luck - I have just checked and the if is not triggering. If I add an else on the if it triggers the else. I'm out of ideas!

Comment: Could you post a broader code sample, i.e. the way you assign the string to the `$message` variable?

Comment: I have put a broader sample in the main message!

Comment: With the exception of the typo in `Write-Host` at the end, that code block works. I suspect that the messages in the log aren't in the format you expect. Add the line `Write-Host "MESSAGE: $message"` immediately after `$message = $event.message` to see what the contents of $message are in each iteration.

Comment: BTW, this is just based on a hunch, but try using `'Destination: (.*?)Start time:'` as your regex (note the added "?").

Comment: ...and if that doesn't work, try `'(?m)Destination: (.*?)Start time:'`. I suspect that the log entries might have more than one occurrence of "Start time:", in which case using a greedy quantifier will match from the first instance of "Destination: " to the *last* instance of "Start time:", whereas a non-greedy quantifier will match to the first instance of "Start time:" that follows "Destination: ".

Comment: Hi Adi - Thanks for your input. Neither made a difference but I tried outputting as you suggested and something interesting I noticed the output looks like this Destination: Network Location NEW LINE IN POWERSHELL Start Time: 26/04/2013 NEW LINE IN POWERSHELL could whatever is causing this new line be causing the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I'm posting as an answer this time, for more flexible formatting, and because I'm confident this will finally solve the problem. ;)

Try this:

```
$destinationregex = '(?s)Destination: ([^\r\n]*).*?Start time:'
```

The `(?s)` means that wildcards can match newline characters. The grouping `([^\r\n]*)` matches until the end of the line, and the `.*?` matches the line break. The following would work too:

`$destinationregex = 'Destination: (.*?)\r\nStart time:'`

In fact, since you really only want to match from after "Destination: " to the end of the line, you could just do this, which is the simplest (unless you specifically want to make sure that you only match if "Start time:" is the very next thing):

`$destinationregex = 'Destination: (.*)'`

If it still doesn't work, it may be because $message is being read as an array instead of a string. You can easily test that by adding the debugging line `$message.GetType()` immediately after setting $message. If it's an array, try setting $message this way (in addition to using one of the regular expressions above):

`$message = $event.message | Out-String`

In fact, doing it this way works in either case, but the `| Out-String` is superfluous if it's already a string, though it doesn't hurt.

For clarity, here's the modified code block, as I *think* it will end up, depending on the answers to the questions above:

```
foreach ($event in $events)
{
  $message = $event.message | Out-String
  $destinationregex = 'Destination: (.*)'
  If ($message -match $destinationregex)
  {
    $destination = $matches[1]
  }
  else
  {
    $destination = "Unknown"
  }
  Write-Host $destination
}
```